# Switch Case Calling A Function Based On The User's Choice

Tags: c#

I got a calculator like program

If the user enters 1 they can add, 2 to subtract, 3 to multiply and 4 to divide

I got functions named

```
         add
         subtract
         multiply
         divide
```

By using switch case, if the user enters 1 it has to go to the add function
2 to subtract, 3 to multiply and 4 to divide.

This is the code i got:

```
          static void Main()
          {         

                 Console.WriteLine("Enter any number");
                 int a = Convert.ToInt32(ConsoleReadLine());
                 Console.WriteLine("Enter any number");
                 int b = Convert.ToInt32(ConsoleReadLine());
                 int c;
                 Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, 3 to multiply and 4 to divide");
                 int Choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                 switch (Choice)
                   case 1:

                       break;
                     //and so forth.
                 public void add()
                 {
                       c = a + b;
                      // similar codes for subtraction,multiplication and division.
                 }
```

In switch case if the user enters 1 the add function should be invoked.
How can i do it?
Any suggestions.
It's asking for object references please help

Comment: You have attempted to declare the add function inside the body of main. It would need to be a function declared outside of the body of main before you can call it. You would probably want to pass `a`and `b` in and return a value to assign to `c`.

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need to use functions? This seems pretty straight forward:

```
switch (Choice)
{
    case 1:
        c = a + b;
        break;
    ...
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice");
        break;
}
```

But if you really do want to use functions, just define them outside of your `Main` method (they must be declared as `static` if you want to call them from `Main`):

```
public static int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

And then invoke them like this:

```
switch (Choice)
{
    case 1:
        c = add(a, b);
        break;
    ...
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call you function and return the result :

```
static void Main()
{        
         Console.WriteLine("Enter any number");
         int a = Convert.ToInt32(ConsoleReadLine());
         Console.WriteLine("Enter any number");
         int b = Convert.ToInt32(ConsoleReadLine());
         int c;
         Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, 3 to multiply and 4 to divide");
         int Choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
         switch (Choice)
           case 1:
                c = add(a,b);
               break;
             //and so forth.
}

public static int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should just call the add function in switch case

```
switch (Choice)
               case 1:
                   add();
                   break;
                 //and so forth.
             public void add()
             {
                   c = a + b;
                  // similar codes for subtraction,multiplication and division.
             }
```

Comment: I don't think this clarifies anything. I believe OP is confused about where and how to declare `add`, which you haven't addressed. Also, even if you did declare `add` correctly, it still won't compile as is because `a`, `b` and `c` are all local variables of `Main`

Comment: @p.s.w.g: actually the code will compile correctly as the add function is defined within the scope if the `Main()` (as far as i know)
i inferred from the question that the author doesn't know how to call the function in switch case, so i addressed that part. :)

Comment: No. In C#, you cannot declare a function inside another function (with the exception of anonymous functions which are an entirely different topic). This won't compile at all.